# Why was Charlie horrified when he looked inside the toilet?

Tags: plot-explanation, daddy-day-care

In "Daddy Day Care", why does Charlie look horrified when he looks inside the Toilet after Max says

> I missed

Why didn't we (the Audience) see what was inside the Toilet?

Comment: he missed to put the dunk at the right place and when seeing someone else has done that, it looks horrifying and scary and gross

Comment: Its a deleted scene, give me 10 minutes I'll show it to you.  Seriously, how is this question a good question?

Comment: It would have turned the scene from funny, to just plain gross.

Answer (score 2):

> Why was Charlie horrified when he looked inside the toilet?

The expression, head movements and music cues are enough to indicate the extreme *disgustingness* and extent of the mess Max made.

> Why didn't we (the Audience) see what was inside the Toilet?

### Because we didn't need to.

Also, this is a family friendly PG movie. There's no need to show puddles of urine or worse when you have Eddie Murphy to make it obvious how bad it was.